# Expand and Collapse HTML Table Data Rows

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I am running into issues over and over. I have a pretty solid HTML table functionality wise, but because it is going to contain so many rows of data, I would like a way to simplify the functionality as well. I want to group rows of data that have a the same "Program Field" and create a expand/collapse function that will hide/display all of the rows with the same program field.

Here is an example of what my table outputs. For example, there are two programs with X as the value I would like to create a row that says "x" and be able to click it and it drops down all rows with the "x" value and if I click again it will collapse them.

[image: Example output results]

This YouTube video is pretty much exactly what I would like to accomplish, but is hard to follow as all of this person's data is hard coded/static as mine is getting pulled through requests.

[YouTube Video of Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svGUH4zSJTU)

Here is my code:

```
<script src="/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var webAppUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

function loadData(source, url) {
  return fetch(url, { headers: { accept: "application/json; odata=verbose" } }) // make request
    .then((r) => {
      if (!r.ok) throw new Error("Failed: " + url);  // Check for errors
      return r.json();  // parse JSON
    })
    .then((data) => data.d.results) // unwrap to get results array
    .then((results) => {
      results.forEach((r) => (r.source = source)); // add source to each item
      return results;
    });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  Promise.all([
    loadData("xDeliverables", "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('xDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
    loadData("yDeliverables", "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('yDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
    loadData("zDeliverables", "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('zDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
  ])
    .then(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
      const objItems = r1.concat(r2,r3);
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Deliverable</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      }
      $("#deliverables").append(tableContent);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("Error: " + err);
      console.error(err);
    });
});
function searchTable() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("deliverablesTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/698627-icon-111-search-256.png');
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#deliverablesTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#deliverablesTable th, #deliverablesTable td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
}

#deliverablesTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#deliverablesTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

#deliverablesTable tr.header, #deliverablesTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
<div id="EmployeePanel">
   <table id='deliverablesTable' style="width: 100%;" border="1 px">
     <tr>
       <td>
          <div id="deliverables" style="width: 100%"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a row after the first occurrence of each Program, and assign the searchTable() function on click of that row:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
//Create a empty array
  var programs = new Array();
  Promise.all([
    loadData("xDeliverables", "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('xDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
    loadData("yDeliverables", "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('yDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
    loadData("zDeliverables", "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('zDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"),
  ])
    .then(([r1, r2, r3]) => {
      const objItems = r1.concat(r2,r3);
      var tableContent =
        '<table id="deliverablesTable" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><strong>Program</strong></td>' +
        "<td><strong>To</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Date Submitted</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Approved</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Notes</strong></td>" +
        "<td><strong>Deliverable</strong></td>" +
        "</tr></thead><tbody>";

      for (var i = 0; i < objItems.length; i++) {
        if (programs.indexOf(objItems[i].Program)==-1){
          //first occurrence of this Program
          programs.push(objItems[i].Program);
          tableContent += '<tr><td colspan="*" class="searchRow">'+objItems[i].Program+ '</td><tr>';
        }
        tableContent += "<tr>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Program + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].To + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Date + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Approved + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Notes + "</td>";
        tableContent += "<td>" + objItems[i].Deliverable + "</td>";
        tableContent += "</tr>";
      }
      $(tableContent).find('.searchRow').click(function(){
         searchTable($(this).text());
      })
      $("#deliverables").append(tableContent);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      alert("Error: " + err);
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Alter searchTable so it can accept a parameter. If the parameter is not null, assign it to the search input box.

```
function searchTable(srch) {
  if(srch!=== undefined){
    $('#myInput').val(srch)
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("deliverablesTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
```

You could handle the parameter / input box in a different way, depending on whether you want the user input to override the row click, or vice versa.

Comment: Im aware I did not paste all of the code into the snippet. I have one that works perfectly fine, that is not the issue I am trying to solve.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but the table doesn't appear after inserting this code, just the searchbox.

Comment: edited - I cant test it, so you may need to step through in the debugger to find the problem.

Comment: Just checked and the only thing that I can find is a CORS issue, which is weird because I wasn't experiencing any of those before since I am pulling from same site.

Comment: I fixed an error I made, but you still may need to step through in a debugger. The CORS issue may be a red herring.